# How can I force Windows (2008 in my case) to reload the fonts folder?

Tags: windows, fonts

After installing a new font in Windows, the font is only available outside your session after a restart.  Is there some way to force Windows to recheck the fonts folder without a restart?  My production servers are 24/7 and I'd rather not have to restart them every time I add or change a custom made font.

Comment: I've found that hitting F5 (one time, several times, it depends) to refresh the Fonts folder in Explorer can sometimes do it. However, I'm the guy who absolutely hated Vista due to endless font corruption, so I don't install fonts any more, unless software does it for me.

Comment: I dont know, but i would wonder if there was a program already that has a font cache clearing in it , that might toss a refresh in on the side?  or if there is some font "services" there in what your running, that can be stopped and restarted that would also refresh things.  The programs themselves making font lists, would still have to be start stopped anyways from how most of them act here.

Comment: yes that's what I'm looking for, some program or utility or some way of having windows 'refresh' its font cache

Comment: Ccleaner has a font cache deleting cleanup in its list of stuff, because ccleaner can be useful, you could try that.

Answer (score 2):

The font cache is located in the %systemroot%\system32 folder, Fntcache.dat file.

If you're in a similar situation, but can afford a restart, you so need to delete c:\windows\system32\fntcache.dat file. It will then be regenerated at next reboot.

If not, a way to force the fntcache.dat regeneration should be investigated. You maybe have find a case for a suggestion request. Servers windows products suggestions are welcome could be given at the following URL: http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/windows/

Comment: OP was asking *"Is there some way to force Windows to recheck the fonts folder without a restart?"*

Comment: Thank you to have made me noticed the answer could be improved gronostaj. I addded a paragraph with a change request solution.